# A no refresh documentation page and how it is done

Tags: javascript, routes, uikit, getuikit

I noticed some documentation web page dose not require refresh to load the content, thus the sidebar/menu is always there and only the content is updated.

I am a graphic designer and i am creating a simple documentation page for a brand logo guide, I am not really good at backend and I am looking for a framework that would load and route navigation without constantly refreshing each page.
This is not iframe i suppose.

Is this pure javascript reloading page content e.g. $( "#div" ).load( "mycontent.html" );, or what should i look into to create a similar web page?

Comment: yes you can almost overwrite anything in page with javascript.

Comment: $( "#div" ).load( "mycontent.html" );, is jQuery lib funcrionality.If you start use vanilla javascript see eyample below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code (vanilla javascript) how you would attach an event listener to all navlinks causing the action when clicked:

```
/* Reload view content when changing tabs/nav-links */
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");
for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    navLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){

  .... Here is the reloding stuff for the selected view 
  Simple way: insert html from predefined files like contentTabX.html (x = 1.. n)
 or load the dynamic generated content from the server/DB 

    }, false);
}
```

You can of course use frameworks like bootstrap4 or similar which provide some functionality, but the price is a lot of (often problematic) overhead.
The best is to learn some basic javascript (vanilla) and use code blocks from trusted sources like stackoverflow

Comment: If i wanted to have the weblink like  "http://myweb/page-2" keyed into address bar and route/load content to page-2, can javascript achieve that?

Comment: Yes and no. NO: This is normally done on the server side in the routing rules. YES: You could catch the input in the address bar and change it anyway you like it. If you mean showing the user TheBestWebpage and leading to  myweb/page-2 thats done in HTML of the link.

Comment: i hv been looking around to achieve that, and i think i can use url query like ?page=mypage to get and load the corresponding data whne page is load. And then update the content and url query when user click for other pages along the way. If i m correct on working my code towards this logic?

Comment: Write some test code and try. If you need help again post your code in a new question and we will help you